# FCM Token Never Created on Launch

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an `iOS` app that uses `Firebase` for remote notifications. For some reason, when testing my app, I never receive the registered `fcmToken` on launch despite documentation stating:

> By default, the FCM SDK generates a registration token for the client app instance on app launch. Similar to the APNs device token, this token allows you to send targeted notifications to any particular instance of your app.

I configure `FirebaseApp` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` `AppDelegate` delegate function, I set `Messaging.messaging().delegate = self` and `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self` thereafter.

Neither `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken`, `didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError`, nor `didReceiveRegistrationToken` delegate functions are called.

Now, what did trigger `didReceiveRegistrationToken` was when I added `UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()` alongside the aforementioned configurations.

Is this how it was always supposed to be/should be? For some reason, I had received the token without this previously and only called `registerForRemoteNotifications()` at the point I actually needed to ask the user to allow for push notifications. Now, I don't.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

FirebaseApp.configure()
attemptRegisterForNotification()
return true
}

private func attemptRegisterForNotification() {
Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
print("didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError \(error)")
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {

print("didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken \(deviceToken)")

Auth.auth().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: .unknown)
Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
}

func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String?) {
print("Firebase FCM \(fcmToken)")
}
```

Comment: is user allowed notification permission ?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri yes, but im more wondering why the token isn't generated on app launch absent of whether or not the user grants notification permission.